# Is there any alternatives to PostgreSQL95Dialect on upgrade to Spring boot 3.0.0 above

Tags: hibernate, upgrade, dialect

Is there any alternatives to PostgreSQL95Dialect on upgrade to Spring boot 3.0.0 above.
Am upgrading the application to  Spring boot 3.0.2 version.But I see PostgreSQL95Dialect  is deprecated .What is the alternative for PostgreSQL95Dialect and  registerHibernateType?

```
 class CustomPostgreSQLDialect extends PostgreSQL95Dialect {

    public CustomPostgreSQLDialect() {
        super();
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, StringArrayType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, IntArrayType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonStringType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonBinaryType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonNodeBinaryType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonNodeStringType.class.getName());
    }
}
```

Is there any alternatives to PostgreSQL95Dialect on upgrade to Spring boot 3.0.0 above.
Am upgrading the application to  Spring boot 3.0.2 version.But I see PostgreSQL95Dialect  is deprecated .What is the alternative for PostgreSQL95Dialect and  registerHibernateType?

```
 class CustomPostgreSQLDialect extends PostgreSQL95Dialect {

    public CustomPostgreSQLDialect() {
        super();
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, StringArrayType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, IntArrayType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonStringType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonBinaryType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonNodeBinaryType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonNodeStringType.class.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Hibernate 6 you do *not* need to explicitly specify the dialect, and you should let Hibernate choose the dialect for you.

From the [migration guide](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.0/migration-guide.adoc#version-specific-and-spaical-specific-dialects-are-deprecated):

> As of Hibernate 6.0, dialects can detect and adapt to the version of the database in use and its spatial capabilities.

On the other hand, to define a *custom dialect* for PostgreSQL you should simply extend  `PostgreSQLDialect`, but then you *do* need to explicitly specify it.

Types may be registered by overriding `contributeTypes()`.

However, a better approach is probably to use a `TypeContributor`, instead of a custom dialect.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve below code using Hibernate 6 above version?   registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, StringArrayType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, IntArrayType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonStringType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonBinaryType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonNodeBinaryType.class.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonNodeStringType.class.getName());

Comment: You don't need that anymore. Hibernate 6.1+ supports array types and JSON out of the box. To use json, annotate a field with `@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)`. For arrays, just omit annotations.